# Getting error trying to show sum result in a textbox on access

Tags: ms-access

I did a function that Sums values on a listbox column on Access, i debugged the function and its calculating the values correctly but when i try to send the result to the textbox i get the #Size! error.

this is the function. Can someone help me?

```
Public Function Somar()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim valor As Double
    For i = 0 To Me.list_vencidos.ListCount - 1
        valor = valor + CDec(Me.list_vencidos.Column(1, i))
    Next i
    Me.txt_soma_vencidos = valor
End Function
```

Comment: Is textbox bound to field?

Comment: Code works for me. Instead of setting textbox value in the procedure, could replace that line with `Somar = valor` and call function from ControlSource: `=Somar()`. Or no VBA and use DSum() expression on the data source.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works for me so can't explain why fails for you.

Because procedure is a function, instead of setting textbox value in the procedure, could replace that line with `Somar = valor` and call function from textbox ControlSource: `=Somar()`. Or no VBA and use DSum() expression on the data source.